# Why am I getting low grades in a subject that I work so hard and studied so well?

Tags: undergraduate, grades, independent-study

What is wrong with me? I studied hard and get so low marks? What am I missing?

I thought I would score 70/80 in COA subject but I got only 49/80. It is a subject where I would even pass if I went to the exam today. I don't understand why is this happening to me. In class 11,12, I would easily get good marks when I studied hard for it. Even before that, I used to get good marks. But nowadays no matter how much I study I keep getting low marks. If I don't study, I fail.

What is wrong with me? I am really frustrated. I study so hard to get low marks... What am I missing? This is really hampering my self confidence and it is going to close many doors for my graduate studies. I am really frustrated with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seem to be at least three potential issues raised by your question. They appear to be conflated in either your thinking, or your question, and it is not clear which is really important.

The first possibility is that you are saying you study hard, understand the material and know the domain but are then somehow  either unable to access your knowledge in an exam situation (e.g., in a multiple choice examination), or able to access your knowledge but unable to express yourself coherently in an exam (e.g., with essay format answers).

Another possibility is that you are saying you put in hours and hours of study but that you find the material incomprehensible even though you think you ought to grasp it.

And thirdly, you might be saying that you study a lot, believe that you have grasped the material, complete the exam believing that you have done well, but then discover that you have done worse than you expected.

In my opinion, it will be impossible for you to solve your problem unless you can first work out which of these issues is at the heart of your apparent failure. The different problems require different solutions. In the absence of more information, it seems foolhardy to make to many suggestions, but briefly:
Problem 1 sounds like something that is usually called "stage fright", "performance anxiety", or "exam anxiety". If this is the problem, I suggest that you talk to a psychologist about solving it. The kind of psychologist you want is one who is not an *analyst* but rather, someone interested in cognitive behavioral therapy for anxiety disorders.

Problem 2 sounds like something that happens fairly commonly to bright high-school students who progress to good colleges and universities; it is touched on by @nick012000 in their answer. You did very well at high-school (i.e., in your local pond). You apply to a good college or university (perhaps one with high standards, where you were surprised, or delighted to have been accepted), and now you are one of a cohort that is quite unlike the one at high-school. Although you were among the brightest of the bright in the high-school pond, in your new environment, you are average or below average in performance, even if not in IQ! The solution here is to accept that you're struggling, and to get some tutorial help.

Problem 3 can be solved by getting more information from your teachers or professors. You will want to discover what it is that you *thought* you understood even though you (demonstrably) did not understand it. You'll want to find out how you misled yourself and what you can do to prevent that from happening in the future, perhaps by finding a way of clearly checking your own understanding *before* it's put to the test in a critical examination. (Quiz books in your relevant area, with answers are a great support here).

Answer (score 1):

#### It's normal. Don't worry about it.

I'm guessing that you used to be one of the smartest kids at your high school, and you studied really hard so that could get into a good university, right?

So did all the other kids in your class. As a result, your course and its marking was designed to take into account the overall higher level of ability possessed by the students, so that they can discriminate between the top students and the middle-of-the-road students within that cohort of students who were talented and driven enough to be admitted to begin with.

As a result of this, you're being held to a higher standard than you were in high school; something that might have earned you an A there might just earn you a C now that you're a university student.

Comment: But there are students who got same marks like me in high school and who are still getting same marks(i.e better than me, same as their high school marks), how are they doing it? They must be doing sth right. I believe I am doing sth wrong, this has been a huge pattern throughout my university. I keep getting low marks than I studied for.

Comment: @TeamB.I It's possible that you're studying in an inefficient or ineffective fashion, that your writing skills aren't up to the expected standard, or some similar deficiency. It's not possible for us to say for sure, since we aren't the ones marking your work. Universities often have academic support sessions that help teach students writing and studying skills, so if you think those might be the root cause they might be able to help you.

Comment: @TeamB.I Otherwise, I can only advise that you talk to some of your professors during their office hours to ask about any deficiencies in your work - not to ask for a higher mark, but to learn why you earned a low mark so that you can fix the problem in the future.

Comment: Our exam copies are checked by professors outside of our college(from same university), so we can't go and ask professors.

Comment: @TeamB.I Even if the exams were marked by other professors, your professors should still be able to help you with figuring out where you went wrong. If all your marks are based off of exams, then I would definitely recommend that you consider attending some study skills classes.

Comment: My Professors can't see my exam copy as they are checked by other teachers from different college than mine. Thanks for recommending study skills classes.

Comment: If what you say is true, the organization of your course sounds like a joke, to be frank. I don't understand why someone would want an education where they can't get any useful feedback from their instructors. You don't get your graded exam back, so that you could bring it to your instructor? How are you supposed to learn from your previous mistakes if you don't know what they are? Your work isn't assessed by the people who run the course and know what material is covered and what the learning objectives are? I feel sorry for the circumstance you are in.

Comment: @BryanKrause: It's common in the UK and many European systems that most of one's marks comes from a final exam that is handled by someone other than the instructor of the course (or at least handled by someone in addition to the course instructor).  This is to ensure that standards are upheld.

Answer (score 0):

@Team B.I, I have seen people face the same problem, it probably must have been due to pressure, the memory where you have stored much of your information could have been replaced by something else, so you must have done something else that must have replaced the information that you studied. It's always good to take a break from doing anything, and then studying again, so then what you studied stays in your mind fresh.